# "Are they American?" or "Are they Americans?"

Tags: differences, adjectives, questions, demonyms

What is the difference between

> Are they **American**?

and

> Are they **Americans**?

Comment: Both are perfectly correct, but I think the singular (adjective) is more common than the plural noun.

Comment: It's the same as the difference between "Are they Danish?" and "Are they Danes?". You don't want to say "Are they Danishes?" because that would mean pastries.

Comment: They are both questions. The corresponding statements are _They are American/Americans_, which is rather like the difference between _They are tired_ and _They are dogs_ -- one is a predicate adjective and the other is a predicate noun.

Comment: This is not a matter of opinion, as @JohnLawler makes clear. Leave open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are correct and mean the same thing. The difference is that in

> Are they American?

*American* is used as an adjective, while in

> Are they Americans?

it is used as a noun in plural form. If there were only one person, the questions would become

> Is he American?

and

> Is he an American?

Comment: I don't think they're quite the same thing. One is "an American" if one is from the United States. One is "American" if one has the characteristics of those from the United States.

Comment: When used without qualification to refer to a person, yes, that's the main meaning. But if you negate them, the difference becomes clearer. You can say someone is "not American" if they act in unAmerican ways. But I don't think you'd say they're "not an American" except to mean that they aren't a native of America.

Answer (score 7):

Although the subject is *they* in both cases, *Are they American?* considers the group as a whole, whereas *Are they Americans?* considers the group as a collection of individuals.

Answer (score 0):

- The americans are lovely people (noun) As a noun, it has SINGULAR AND PLURAL.

They were born in USA, they are AMERICAN (adjective).  Adjectives in English  don't have PLURAL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).